# Viewpager with horizontal as well as vertical scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I am searching for a view pager which should have horizontal and vertical scrolling in one class.It should just need to specify the property which type of scroll we want.How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this link will be helpful for you: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1863. It has both vertical and horizontal features.

Comment: i already tried it only inserts a vertical view pager inside horizontal viewpager where as the viewpager has two clases horizontal viewpager and vertical viewpager. i need a view pager like this but this is depricated      https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager

Comment: Does this link useful ?

Comment: thanks bro it really worked for me let me test in my app if it work.one more thing iam searching for that is horizotal webview how can we set swipe horizontal or vertical of webview

Comment: oh great.Please upvote my answer.Let me check that too.

Comment: boss got one problem it does not accept FragmentPagerAdapter it accepts this adpater PageAdapter i cannot change it to PageAdapter

Comment: still need to add FragmentPagerAdapter and FragmentStatePagerAdapter` subclasses to easily replace those, but if you need them now it shouldn't be difficult. This is comment of same developer.Seems you have to write a for FragmentPagerAdapter support inside lib.

Comment: so how can achive this now it is difficult for me to do so

Comment: In that need to search another lib.Let me check another lib.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124971/discussion-between-awez-shaikh-and-ravi-sahu).